# Primefaces 5.3 push fails on GlassFish 4.1

Tags: primefaces, glassfish, atmosphere, primepush

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The app runs on GF 4.1.1

The error trace:

```
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI definition failure:sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:182)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processAnnotatedTypes(BeanDeployer.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createTypes(BeanDeployment.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:381)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:220)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:600)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getDeclaredAnnotations(Executable.java:591)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:629)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache.internalGetAnnotations(DefaultReflectionCache.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache$1.load(DefaultReflectionCache.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache$1.load(DefaultReflectionCache.java:81)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache.getAnnotations(DefaultReflectionCache.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.RequiredAnnotationDiscovery.containsAnnotation(RequiredAnnotationDiscovery.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.containsAnnotation(ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.java:172)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.containsRequiredAnnotations(ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeObserverResolver.matches(TypeSafeObserverResolver.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeObserverResolver.matches(TypeSafeObserverResolver.java:37)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver.findMatching(TypeSafeResolver.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver.access$000(TypeSafeResolver.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver$ResolvableToBeanCollection.load(TypeSafeResolver.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver$ResolvableToBeanCollection.load(TypeSafeResolver.java:44)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver.resolve(TypeSafeResolver.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.resolveObserverMethods(ObserverNotifier.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:180)
    ... 47 more

Grave:   Exception while loading the app
Grave:   Undeployment failed for context /Umigon
Grave:   Exception while loading the app : CDI definition failure:sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:182)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processAnnotatedTypes(BeanDeployer.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createTypes(BeanDeployment.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:381)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:600)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getDeclaredAnnotations(Executable.java:591)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:629)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache.internalGetAnnotations(DefaultReflectionCache.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache$1.load(DefaultReflectionCache.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache$1.load(DefaultReflectionCache.java:81)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache.getAnnotations(DefaultReflectionCache.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.RequiredAnnotationDiscovery.containsAnnotation(RequiredAnnotationDiscovery.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.containsAnnotation(ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.java:172)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.containsRequiredAnnotations(ProcessAnnotatedTypeEventResolvable.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeObserverResolver.matches(TypeSafeObserverResolver.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeObserverResolver.matches(TypeSafeObserverResolver.java:37)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver.findMatching(TypeSafeResolver.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver.access$000(TypeSafeResolver.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver$ResolvableToBeanCollection.load(TypeSafeResolver.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver$ResolvableToBeanCollection.load(TypeSafeResolver.java:44)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.TypeSafeResolver.resolve(TypeSafeResolver.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.resolveObserverMethods(ObserverNotifier.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:180)
    ... 47 more
```

I googled and searched on the primefaces forum for hours - no clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those in the same situation, I have created a toy project demonstrating a config with PF 5.3, GF 4.1.1 and the push Atmosphere framework:

https://github.com/seinecle/RealTimeOpinion